# Approach to build multivariate ranking system?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, multilinear-algebra, valuation-theory, descriptive-statistics

I have data of various sellers on ecommerce platform. I am trying to compute seller ranking score based on various features, such as

1] Order fulfillment rates [numeric]

2] Order cancel rate [numeric]

3] User rating [1-5] { 1-2 : Worst, 3: Average , 5: Good} [categorical]

4] Time taken to confirm the order. (shorter the time taken better is the seller) [numeric]

My first instinct was to  normalize all the features, then multiply parameters/feature by some weight . Add them together for each seller score. Finally, find relative ranking of sellers based on this score.

My Seller score equation looks like

Seller score = w1* Order fulfillment rates -  w2*Order cancel rate  + w3 * User rating + w4 * Time taken to confirm order

where,  w1,w2,w3,w4 are weights.

My question is three fold

Are there better algorithms/approaches to solve this problem? i.e I linearly added the various features, I want to know better approach to build the ranking system?

How to come with the values for the weights?

Apart from using above features, few more that I can think of are ratio of positive to negative reviews, rate of damaged goods etc. How will these fit into my Score equation?

How to incorporate numeric and categorical variables in finding seller ranking score? (I have few categorical variables)

Is there an accepted way to weight multivariate systems like this in a better way and build a ranking system in general?
Any reading suggestions are welcome

Comment: Part of the issue here is, do you have any objective way of knowing the seller score ahead of time, at least for some amount of sellers? Or maybe you would like to recommend new sellers to a user who has already ranked sellers they like? If you did have this information, you could solve this problem using [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) or similar machine learning algorithms. If not, it seems like picking the weights is an ambiguous problem. How would you know if the ranking is correct? How do you decide if your algorithms has succeeded or failed?

Comment: I dont have seller score ahead of time.

Comment: If that is the case, this appears to be an ambiguous problem. You could pick any weights you like, but you would have nothing to validate the results of your model other than your own intuition. Most automated ranking systems that I'm aware of extrapolate from a dataset where the results are already known--this is what the field of supervised machine learning attempts to accomplish. Without at least some known results, I don't know how you can tell a good result from a bad result.

Comment: As an aside, you may want to check out Cross Validated http://stats.stackexchange.com/, which is more relevant for statistics and machine learning.